# I'm not getting the right random value. There are 6 values in my database. I give Limit 3. But the first 4 items shows randomized

Tags: php, mysql, sql, web

I need 3 question from 6. but every time randomize show fast 4 question.

```
    /*for random question*/
public function qustionShow($question){

    $query = $this->conn->query("select * from question where cat_id='$question'");
    $c = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    $rand = rand(3, $c)-3;


    $show = $this->conn->query("select * from question where cat_id ='$question' and id >'$rand' LIMIT 3");
    while ($row=$show->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        $this->qus[]=$row;
    }
    return $this->qus;  
}
```

Comment: Should that limit `...='$question' and id >'$rand' LIMIT 4` be a `3`?

Comment: oh sorry, 
I use 3 in my code.

Comment: ^^^ Doubtful, how did it get here?

Comment: I get 3 question out of 4, but I have 6 question in my database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reduce and optimize your code, using ORDER BY RAND().

Try something like:

```
public function qustionShow($question, $limit=3){
    $show = $this->conn->query("select * from question where cat_id ='$question' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT $limit");
    while ($row=$show->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        $this->qus[]=$row;
    }
    return $this->qus;  
}
```